# Challenging integral $I=\int_0^{\pi/2}x^2\frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\cos x}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, closed-form, polylogarithm

My friend offered to solve this integral.

$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}x^2\frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\cos x}dx=\frac{\pi^4}{32}-{4G^2} $$
Where G is the Catalan's constant.

$$I=\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\arctan ^2\left(u\right)\ln \left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}\:du\;.$$
Put $$\tan{x}=u$$
Inability to split into two integrals, they are divergent.

Comment: Are you sure that $$I=\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\arctan ^2\left(u\right)\ln \left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}\:du\quad ?$$ It seems that $$I=\int _0^{\infty }\arctan ^2\left(u\right)\ln \left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}\right)\sqrt{1+u^2}\:du\;.$$

Comment: Results of similar integrals: $$\int_0^{\pi/2} x\frac{\log(\sin x)\log(\cos x)}{\cos x} dx = \frac{\pi ^2 G}{4}+16 L_4+4 \log (2) L_3-16 \beta(4)+\frac{7 \pi  \zeta (3)}{16}-\frac{1}{24} \pi  \log ^3(2)+\frac{3}{32} \pi ^3 \log (2)$$
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} x\frac{\log^2(\sin x)}{\cos x} dx = \frac{\pi ^2 G}{6}-2 G \log ^2(2)-16 L_4-8 \log (2) L_3+8 \beta(4)+\frac{7 \pi  \zeta (3)}{8}+\frac{1}{6} \pi  \log ^3(2)$$
here $\beta$ is Dirichlet Beta function, $L_n = \Im \text{Li}_n(\frac{1+i}{2})$.

Comment: @pisco very interesting,thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible way to calculate it is starting with  $x=\frac{\pi }{2}-t$, we then get
$$\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}x^2\sec \left(x\right)\ln \left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)\:dx=\frac{\pi ^2}{4}\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\csc \left(x\right)\ln \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)\:dx$$
$$-\pi \int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}x\csc \left(x\right)\ln \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)\:dx+\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}x^2\csc \left(x\right)\ln \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)\:dx.\tag1$$
Notice that the first integral is very simple, as for the second one, it won't be necessary to calculate it if we focus on the third integral.

Employing the well-known expansion for $\ln \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)$ leads to
$$\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}x^2\csc \left(x\right)\ln \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)\:dx$$
$$=-\ln \left(2\right)\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}x^2\csc \left(x\right)\:dx-\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^k}{k}\underbrace{\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}x^2\csc \left(x\right)\cos \left(2kx\right)\:dx}_{I_k},\tag2$$
so in order to simplify $I_k$ we'll use the following strategy
$$\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}x^2\csc \left(x\right)\cos \left(2kx\right)\:dx=\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}x^2\frac{\cos \left(2kx\right)}{\sin \left(x\right)}\:dx$$
$$I_k=\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}x^2\frac{\cos \left(2kx\right)}{\sin \left(x\right)}\:dx$$
$$I_{n+1}-I_n=\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}x^2\frac{\cos \left(2\left(n+1\right)x\right)-\cos \left(2nx\right)}{\sin \left(x\right)}\:dx=-2\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}x^2\sin \left(\left(2n+1\right)x\right)\:dx$$
$$=-\frac{2\pi \left(2n+1\right)\left(-1\right)^n-4}{\left(2n+1\right)^3}$$
$$I_k-I_0=-\sum _{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{2\pi \left(2n+1\right)\left(-1\right)^n-4}{\left(2n+1\right)^3}$$
$$\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}x^2\csc \left(x\right)\cos \left(2kx\right)\:dx=-2\pi \sum _{n=1}^k\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{\left(2n-1\right)^2}+4\sum _{n=1}^k\frac{1}{\left(2n-1\right)^3}+\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}x^2\csc \left(x\right)\:dx.$$
Replacing this in $\left(2\right)$ yields
$$=2\pi \sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^k}{k}\sum _{n=1}^k\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{\left(2n-1\right)^2}-4\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^k}{k}\sum _{n=1}^k\frac{1}{\left(2n-1\right)^3}$$
$$=-2\pi \int _0^1\left(\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^k}{k}\left(1-\left(-x^2\right)^k\right)\right)\frac{\ln \left(x\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx$$
$$-2\int _0^1\left(\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^k}{k}\left(1-x^{2k}\right)\right)\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)}{1-x^2}\:dx$$
$$=-2\pi \int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(x\right)\ln \left(\frac{1-x^2}{2}\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx-2\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln \left(\frac{1+x^2}{2}\right)}{1-x^2}\:dx.$$
Lastly, notice that
$$-2\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(x\right)\ln \left(\frac{1-x^2}{2}\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx=\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}x\csc \left(x\right)\ln \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)\:dx$$
$$\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln \left(\frac{1+x^2}{2}\right)}{1-x^2}\:dx=2G^2-\frac{45}{16}\zeta \left(4\right),$$
where in order to obtain such closed-form one can trivially reduce it to the derivatives of the Beta function or exploit symmetry with double integration.

Now that we know what $\left(2\right)$ transformed to, $\left(1\right)$ becomes
$$\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}x^2\sec \left(x\right)\ln \left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)\:dx$$
$$=\frac{\pi ^2}{4}\left(-\frac{\pi ^2}{8}\right)-\pi \int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}x\csc \left(x\right)\ln \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)\:dx-2\pi \left(-\frac{1}{2}\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}x\csc \left(x\right)\ln \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)\:dx\right)$$
$$-2\left(2G^2-\frac{45}{16}\zeta \left(4\right)\right),$$
and finally
$$\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}x^2\sec \left(x\right)\ln \left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)\:dx=\frac{45}{16}\zeta \left(4\right)-4G^2.$$

Comment: (+1) very well Thank you very much